# Integral domain existence problem

Tags: ring-theory

does there exist any integral domain of order 10

if we show that the integral domain has an element of order greater than 5,then 2a.5a=0 where a is that element.then it contradicts that ring has no zero divisors then it can be proved that there does not exist such id

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no. Try to prove it following these exercises:

> **Exercise 1**: let $a \in R$. If $R$ is an integral domain, then the map $R \rightarrow R$ given by $$r \mapsto ar$$ is injective.

Conclude that, if $R$ is a finite integral domain, then $R$ is a field.

> **Exercise 2**: if $R$ is a finite field, then $R$ has $p^n$ elements, for some positive integer $n$ and prime $p$.

Hint: let $p > 0$ be the characteristic of $R$. Show that $R$ is a vector space over $\mathbf Z / p \mathbf Z$